How to set odd saturdays as working in odoo v15?
Is there anyway we can set odd saturdays as working for every month? Currently if we set first saturday as working in resource.calander(working times), it will goes wrong after a month with 3 saturday occurs. Company dont want to set the second and fourth saturdays as public holiday
